# Why this f# code does not compile?

Tags: f#

I would expect it to be a function that accepts two strings and returns an option of an integer.

```
 let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) = f >> function
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: (true, item)

"This expression was expected to have type
    'string -> bool * int'    
but here has type
    ''a * 'b'
". 

The compiler assumed that the resulting function takes one argument. I would like to understand why this decision was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` accepts two parameters. `>>` only curries a single parameter. You can get it to compile by writing it this way:

```fsharp
let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) =
      fun a -> f a >> function
                      | (true, item) -> Some item
                      | (false, _) -> None
```

Or you could include that first parameter in the function signature itself, like this:

```fsharp
let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) a = f a >> function
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easier to explain by expanding the code out so there's less function passing/composition.

Let's remove the compose operator `>>` and use a pipe `|>` instead, adding an explicit `aString` parameter:

```
let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) aString =
    f aString |> function
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None
```

Now let's use `fun` instead of `function` with an explicit parameter `x`:

```
let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) aString =
    f aString
    |> fun x ->
        match x with
        | (true, item) -> Some item
        | (false, _) -> None
```

Now let's remove the pipe altogether by inlining the `fun`:

```
let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) aString =
    match (f aString : string -> bool * int) with
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None
```

This code is equivalent to what you started with. `f aString` is the `f` function with just one string applied to it. Because of currying, the type of this expression is `string -> bool * int`. I added a type annotation in the code above to prove this. Another string needs to be supplied before it produces a result of `bool * int`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 

But why doesn't compiler choose the following code to be equivalent: 

`let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) aString bString =
    f aString bString |> function
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None`

Comment: Because it's not equivalent! :) It doesn't follow the syntax rules of the language to treat them as the same thing. The `>>` cannot dynamically work out how many arguments to pass in a static type system. To keep the same structure you could define the operator `let (>>+) f g a b = f a b |> g` and use that instead. However, please don't do that as it would be unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Got it finally ) 

The >> operator is defined with a single argument 
This is the way I was expecting it to work: 

`let (>>+) f g x y = f x y |> g
 let helper (f : string -> string -> bool * int) = f >>+ function
    | (true, item) -> Some item
    | (false, _) -> None`

Thanks!